# I want to convert my joomla URL into user friendly URLs

Tags: php, .htaccess, joomla, seo

I want to convert my joomla(version 2.5) URL structure that has component/id into user friendly or SEO friendly URLs.
?option=com_mycomponent&view=myview&id=98
into
myarticle.php or sometext.php

I do have some customized components also which needs to be changed.

Can anyone help?

Comment: See https://docs.joomla.org/Enabling_Search_Engine_Friendly_%28SEF%29_URLs_on_Apache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used MijoSEF component for customizing the URL into user friendly URLs. For customized component, I have created rounter.php in each customized component. So that it process the SEO friendly URLs in the joomla url structure. After all, you need menu items for each action in the URL

http://miwisoft.com/joomla-extensions/mijosef-joomla-seo-sef-urls

Download the free version by clicking the above URL and install
Once installed, you can see the list of components in your website. your component will be listed only if you have the router file in it. 
Once selected the components, you can change each and every URL in your website. 
See the sample router which I have used based on the requirement.

```
<?php
/**
 * @package     Joomla.Site
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2005 - 2012 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

jimport('joomla.application.categories');

/**
 * Build the route for the com_content component
 *
 * @param   array   An array of URL arguments
 * @return  array   The URL arguments to use to assemble the subsequent URL.
 * @since   1.5
 */
function MycomponentBuildRoute(&$query)
{
    $segments   = array();
    if (isset($query['Itemid'])) {
        $segments[] = $query['Itemid'];
        unset($query['Itemid']);
    }   
    if(isset($query['task'])) {
        $segments[] = $query['task'];
        unset($query['task']);
    }
    if(isset($query['id'])) {
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        $aquery = $db->setQuery($db->getQuery(true)
            ->select('alias')
            ->from('#__content')
            ->where('id='.(int)$query['id'])
        );
        $alias = $db->loadResult();
        $query['id'] = $query['id'].':'.$alias;
        $segments[] = $query['id'];
        unset($query['id']);
    }   
    return $segments;
}

/**
 * Parse the segments of a URL.
 *
 * @param   array   The segments of the URL to parse.
 *
 * @return  array   The URL attributes to be used by the application.
 * @since   1.5
 */
function MycomponentParseRoute($segments)
{
    $vars = array();
    $vars['Itemid'] = $segments[0];
    $vars['task']   = $segments[1];
    $vars['id'] = $segments[2];
    return $vars;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For core components and most well known [extensions found on the JED](http://extensions.joomla.org/) it's pretty easy to enable SEF URLs by enabling the `.htaccess` file (or it's equivalent) and changing the Global Configuration settings.

I would suggest the following reading for your requirements.

1. Joomla has built-in support for SEF URL's. (See [Search Engine Friendly URLs](https://docs.joomla.org/Search_Engine_Friendly_URLs))
2. For your custom components you will have to add support for SEF URLs if you haven't already. (See [Supporting SEF URLs in your component](https://docs.joomla.org/Supporting_SEF_URLs_in_your_component))

Finally, if you need more Joomla specific support try [the Joomla Q&A on StackExchange](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)